# R Reactive filtering of data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this plot that has reactive input to genre. Since my dataset has changed since last time (I am using ggplot2movies now), the filtering does not work anymore. I was wondering how to fix this, since I have no clue.

I was thinking something along the lines of this, but it does not work

```
  ggimdb <- data.frame(ggplot2movies::movies)
  imdbmovies <- reactive({
    genre <- input$genre
    k <- ggimdb %>%
      filter(
        genre == 1
      )
  })
```

This is part of the dataframe of the movies
[image]

The `input$genre` obviously is a selection box which can select one genre. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What about `k <- ggimdb[, colnames(ggimdb) %in% genre]`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Hmm I tried this, but seems to give this error for me `no applicable method for 'compute_density' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"` not sure what causes this specifically

Comment: What about `ggimdb[ggimdb[, colnames(ggimdb) %in% genre] == 1, ]`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik That one works indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `dplyr` is looking for a column named `genre` rather than for a column whose name is held in the variable `genre`. Instead, you need to use `filter_` which allows you to dynamically pick columns by constructing the arguments you want to include:

```
genre <- "Animation"

data.frame(ggplot2movies::movies) %>%
  filter_(paste(genre, "== 1"))
```

works.